# Android Room "bad RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations attribute"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I use Room and when build my project it gave me this error:

[image]

After hours of googling i found that the cause of error is my entity class has 284 field, which is OK for SQLite (limitation is 32767 column for each table) but, java has 255 parameter limitation for a method or constructor.

Here is Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "file_table")
data class TheFile(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "rowId")
var fileId: Int = 0,
@ColumnInfo(name = "name_male")
var name_malek: String="",
@ColumnInfo(name = "tel_male")
var tel_malek: String=""
//[and more...]
```

This is Dao:

```
@Dao
interface TheFileDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM file_table")
fun getAll(): LiveData<List<TheFile>>

}
```

When open [classname]_Impl.java found that room at the end of Dao method create an instance of entity class by using constructor which can't take 284 parameter and cause the error.

```
_result = new TheFile(_tmpFileId,_tmpName_malek,_tmpTel_malek,_tmpTel2_malek,_tmpTel3_malek,_tmpName_mostajer,_tmpTel_mostajer, and_more_parameter);
```

Can you guys gave me any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal to have that many parameters. You need to create some new fields  instead.

Answer (score 0):

Divide those 284 field into different different object and Use those object in Entity class.

**E.g.**

```
@Entity(tableName = "my_table")
public class MyData {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ListData")
    @TypeConverters(DataTypeConverter.class)
    private List<MyListObject> mList = null;
    @Embedded
    private User mUser;
    public MyData() {
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<MyListObject> getList() {
        return mList;
    }

    public void setList(List<MyListObject> list) {
        this.mList = list;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return mUser;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.mUser = user;
    }
}
```